# In a local class, how to reference shadowed variables of enclosing method?

Tags: java, class

I am thinking about this situation while learning [local classes](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/javaOO/localclasses.html) from Oracle's tutorial:

```
class HelloWorldApp {
    public String s = "string in outer class";
    public void shout() {
        final String s = "string in enclosing method";
        class out {
            public String s  = "string in local class";
            public void show()
            {
                System.out.println(s);
                System.out.println(HelloWorldApp.this.s);//reference the member of enclosing class
                System.out.println(HelloWorldApp.this.shout.s)//compiler complaints
            }
        }
        out no = new out();
        no.show();
    }
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        HelloWorldApp h = new HelloWorldApp();
        h.shout();
    }
}
```

Now, I'd like to reference the local variable `s` of method `shout()` in this case, but the tutorial didn't give out the point.

I have searched by Google and  StackOverflow, but I couldn't get the right way out.

Comment: @Makoto yes you can declare classes inside methods

Comment: `Now, I'd like to reference the local variable s` You didn't mention `where` you want to reference it.

Comment: @YaroslavShabalin yes he did.  See the comments in the source.

Answer (score 5):

You can't.

JLS 6.4 says:

> A local variable (§14.4), formal parameter (§8.4.1), exception parameter (§14.20), and local class (§14.3) can only be referred to using a simple name (§6.2), not a qualified name (§6.6).

6.4.1 says:

> Some declarations may be shadowed in part of their scope by another declaration of the same name, in which case a simple name cannot be used to refer to the declared entity.

So you have a situation where a name "can only" be referred to using a simple name (6.4), but it's shadowed so you cannot refer to it using a simple name (6.4.1).  The conclusion is that you're stuck.